# Limits in Differential calculus

Tags: limits, derivatives

I have to prove that 
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}
$$

At first I used the standard definiton
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} 
$$

Then I replace  $-h=u$, which gives me 
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-u)}{u} 
$$

But then how I replace in $\lim_{ h\to0}$  in  $u$?

Comment: to use LaTex here use dollars signs {$} to *enclose* the mathematical expression. Double dollar sign gives you a new line and bigger symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $\;u=-h\;$  , so that $\;h\to 0\iff u\to 0\;$ , and then

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{{f(x)-f(x-h)}}h=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x+u)}{-u}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{f(x+u)-f(x)}u=f'(x)$$

Comment: Thank you but i have one question  is that ture :$\;-h\to 0\iff u\to 0\;$

Comment: @Peterpeter, can't you prove it, say via arithmetic of limits (if you want to be very formal), or otherwise?

Comment: $\;-h\to 0$  then  $\; h\to 0$  

because
$\;-h\to 0$ => $  
\left \| -h \right \|=\left \| h \right \|<\epsilon $

so the limits are the same?

is this correct?

Comment: Well, yes: in short, not so formal but clear words.